# Apex Oracle 5.1.2: i can't find element properties

Tags: input, width, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I can't find element properties in Apex 5.1.2. I have to change an input width, where is the properties size?

In Apex 5.0 was like this: 
[image: in apex 5.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe it does exists in 5.1.2. May be the page item was defined as hidden or display only or select list?

Comment: Yes, It was the problem. The items was display only. Thanks so much!